# how to get a copy of a deleted answer

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Apparently an answer I wrote was deleted (by others).

Is there a way to retrieve a deleted answer? (I would like to
keep a copy of it)

Comment: Do you remember the question to which you posted the answer?

Comment: Do you mean https://askubuntu.com/a/1150841/367990 ? I am not 100% sure, but I think you should be able to see your own deleted answers when you visit its page.

Comment: @ByteCommander, thank you: that is it, and I can see it!(I could not find it -- it also disappeared from my answers list, activity, etc). I hate deleters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My apologies: I was one of the "deleters".**

This is the system-wide deletion logic:

- a moderator can delete anything (no mod deleted anything)
- 5 reviewers voting to delete can delete anything (None did)
- in your case 3 high-rep (>20000 rep) reviewers agreed that:

  - this was not a good answer
  - one of them downvoted your answer
  - all 3 cast a delete vote

and your answer was subsequently deleted.

Please allow me to explain the logic why *I voted to delete:*

- The answer was wrong,
- The answer just provides `the codez` without any explanation (yeah, comments inside the code don't count as explanation)
- The question already had an answer that was more elegant, upvoted and accepted.

Unfortunately, the users here don't maintain the site logic and features: [Stack Exchange Employees do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) and though we would all like to see all of our deleted questions / answers, the powers that be decided to decline this feature request, but you did the right thing to ask about it here, you got your answer back and you can still [edit and improve it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1150841/367990) and ping the 3 of us [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and we'll undelete it for you...

<sub>**Also please don't hate:** Fear is the path to the dark side: Fear leads to anger. Anger leads to hate. Hate leads to suffering. **;-)**</sub>

Comment: thank for the style! Why is the answer wrong?

Comment: Read terdon's comments below your [deleted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1150841/367990)...  **0:-)**

Comment: I read them, of course. Terdon's comments were about a previous version (in fact an unfinished answer). Have you read my answer? Can you show me a wrong answer situation?